# Converting Combobox Value.Member from Sttring to Integer?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 comboboxes which contain ID columns (SID & CID) as the valuemember and the displayMember is text.
I want to use the valueMembers to INSERT into an SQL database.
However the ValueMember property is a String and the column in the database is an Integer.

How can I get these 2 valueMembers converted into Integers.
The code for the complete form is shown below.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports My_Greeting.Add_VersesDataSetTableAdapters

Public Class frmAddRecord
    Private MyDatAdp As New SqlDataAdapter
    Private MyDataTbl As New DataTable
    Private sql As String = Nothing
    Private ds As New DataSet()
    Private stepinfo As String = String.Empty
    Dim E1 As String
    Dim E2 As String
    Dim Verse As String

    Private connectionString As String = "Data Source=DESKTOP-S7FRNAL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Verses_Find;Integrated Security=True"

    Private Sub frmAddRecord_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Me.Sub_EventTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.EventSubDataSet1.Sub_Event)
        Me.Event_TypeTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.PrimEventDataSet1.Event_Type)
        Dim evt As String
        Dim SEvt As String
        Dim Verse As String
        Dim sql As String = Nothing
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim stepinfo As String = String.Empty
        Try
            stepinfo = "Step: instatiate connection"
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                stepinfo = "step: test open connection"
                connection.Open()
                sql = "Select SID, EVENT from Event_Type"
                Using adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
                    adaptor.Fill(ds, "Tab_Event_Type")
                End Using
                stepinfo = "Load second data"
                sql = "Select BID,SUBEVENT from Sub_Event"
                Using adaptor As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
                    adaptor.Fill(ds, "Tab_Sub_Event")
                End Using
            End Using
            stepinfo = "Step: Bind Event combobox"
            cboEvent.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tab_Event_Type")
            cboEvent.ValueMember = "SID"
            cboEvent.DisplayMember = "Event"
            stepinfo = "Bind Sub_Event combobox"
            cboSEvent.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tab_Sub_Event")
            cboSEvent.ValueMember = "BID"
            cboSEvent.DisplayMember = "SubEvent"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show($"Error:{stepinfo}{vbNewLine}{ex.ToString}")
        End Try
        evt = cboEvent.ValueMember
        SEvt = cboSEvent.ValueMember
        Verse = txtNewVerse.Text
        E1 = CType(evt, Integer)
        E2 = CType(SEvt, Integer)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO Verse (Event, Event_Sub, Verse)"
        query &= "VALUES (@Event, @Event_Sub, @Verse)"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-S7FRNAL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Verses_Find;Integrated Security=True")
            Using Comm As New SqlCommand()
                With Comm
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event", E1)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Event_Sub", E2)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Verse", Verse)
                End With
                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have tried CInt and CType, but they dont work.

> Conversion from string "SID" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: Couldn't understand your method of displaying code!  It said about adding 4 back ticks so thats what I did. Othersites are much simpler than your sites method!

Comment: The `ValueMember` is the name of the member from which the values come.  It is NOT the value(s).  That's what the `SelectedValue` property is for.  The `SelectedValue` is where you'll find the value from the specified member of the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: *"Othersites are much simpler than your sites method!"*.  Really?  They are easier than selecting the text and clicking the 'Code' button on the editor toolbar?  Do they let you use mind control or something?

Comment: Also, you can't actually get the value from the selection until the selection is made, so trying to get it the moment you bind the data to the control is also nonsensical.  You would either get the selection when the user clicks the `Button` to use it or perhaps handle an appropriate event of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Also, use `CInt(x)` rather than `CType(x, Integer)`.  They are the same code but the first is obviously more readable.

Comment: Please, remove irrelevant code.

Comment: You have a string variable named `evt`.  It's value is "SID".  That value cannot be converted to an `Integer`.  That is what the error is telling you.  In addition, your variables `E1` and `E2` are _string_ variables and you are trying to assign an integer to them which doesn't make sense.  Go into your project's properties and turn `Option Strict On`.  That will help you to find many errors that are in your code.  What you probably want is to use `cboEvent.SelectedValue` to get the value that is currently selected in the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in these lines of code:

```
cboEvent.ValueMember = "SID"
...
Dim evt As String
...
evt = cboEvent.ValueMember
...
Dim E1 As String
...
E1 = CType(evt, Integer)
```

You can simplify it into

```
Dim E1 As String = CType("SID", Integer)
```

Which is obviously not going to work. I'm not sure of your intent, but this is surely your issue.

**Edit** to address your comments

Here is the title of your question `Converting Combobox Value.Member from Sttring [sic] to Integer?`

Let's try to figure out what you are trying to do. (By the way, it is nice when we don't need to try to figure out a questioner's intent; rather it is apparent. Anyway, let's do that now)

Regarding this nugget: `Combobox Value.Member`, it's unclear whether you actually want the [ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.8), [SelectedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_SelectedValue), or [Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.text?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_Text) (Text being the closest proxy to *Value* alone).

The ValueMember tells a control which property to return via [SelectedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_SelectedValue) when the control is data-bound. For example,

```
Dim source = (
    From i In Enumerable.Range(5, 5)
    Select New With {
        .Number = i,
        .Square = i ^ 2
    }).ToList()
ComboBox1.DataSource = source
ComboBox2.DataSource = source
ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Number"
ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Square"
```

Let's see what the results of the three properties in question are, for both ComboBoxes

```
MessageBox.Show($"{ComboBox1.ValueMember}, {ComboBox2.ValueMember}")
```

> , Square

```
MessageBox.Show($"{ComboBox1.Text}, {ComboBox2.Text}")
```

> { Number = 5, Square = 25}, 5

```
MessageBox.Show($"{ComboBox1.SelectedValue}, {ComboBox2.SelectedValue}")
```

> { Number = 5, Square = 25}, 25

The last one is probably what you want. `ComboBox2.ValueMember` has been set as the "Square" property of the anonymous type in the LINQ expression.

So in your example, the offending code is in my first code block, and it should be obvious that assigning `evt = cboEvent.ValueMember` is wrong and that you probably wanted the `SelectedValue`

```
evt = cboEvent.SelectedValue
```

which should have been clear from our comments, and answer. @jmcilhinney's comment specifically

> The `ValueMember` is the name of the member from which the values come. It is NOT the value(s). That's what the `SelectedValue` property is for. The `SelectedValue` is where you'll find the value from the specified member of the `SelectedItem`. – [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney) 16 hours ago

that last part again

> 16 hours ago

You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.

Comment: Isn’t it obvious! I’m trying to get the valueMember from the combobox into the SQL INSERT query? Not very helpful!

Comment: It's not obvious because that's nonsensical.  See my comment on the question to learn why.

Comment: Your quite fond of using the word nonsensical. Is that programmer speak for you don't know you are taking about?  It seemed a straight forward question to me! How do you get a combobox value, which is a string to convert it to an integer so that it can be INSERTED into an SQL database, where the value stored is an Integer.  Can't explain it any simpler than that!!

Comment: @TonyHudson - This answer tells you how.  You use `cboEvent.SelectedValue` and then use either `CInt`, `CType`, or (better) `Integer.TryParse`.